# Can’t get the exact iPhone notch size in Unity

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

Getting the notch size isn't supported in Unity.
I've tried to first get the notch size for all iOS devices in Xcode and then convert them to pixels in Unity but it’s always wrong and I’m not sure why.

No information regarding this can be found on the internet - I think this is because no games require knowing the exact notch size for every iOS device especially in Unity but in my case, I do need it so I can do something with it.

It would be nice to be able to get the position as well (notch and 14 Pro's island)

**I know how to handle safe area in Unity. This is not about that. This is about getting the notch size.**

*Since hardcoding seems to be the only option at this point, I convert these values to px because Xcode uses pt and Unity uses px. However things become too small in Unity when I do that.*

```
var size: CGSize {
    switch self {
    case .large:
        if UIDevice.current.hasSmallNotchArea {
            return .init(width: 206.30, height: 29.10)
        } else {
            return .init(width: 207.50, height: 31.30) 
        }
    case .medium:
        return .init(width: 160.90, height: 33.20)
    case .pill:
        return .init(width: 124, height: 35.20)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried that didn't work? Might be useful to help you spot why it was "always wrong."

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like Unity has any support for giving you that info, so your best bet will likely be to make your own solution by getting the "DeviceGeneration", figuring out if you're on one with the notch and then having a catalogue of the different notch sizes and positions to return.

Probably not what you wanted to hear, but unless someone has put it up as a github repo I couldn't track down, I think you might have to forge the way on this one.

---

Also instead of using pixels, would likely be more reliable to use percentages and space from the edges to generate it on the fly.

Comment: Hmm no using percentages would be a really bad idea and simply, won't work. iPhone notches do not increase or decrease in size depending on the screen resolution. They're fixed.

Comment: Given what you've added to the main question, it might be that you just haven't set up the UI correctly in the scene. Unity UI can be generally a bit finicky to get working as you want it to.

Also the reason I suggest percentages is so you can not have to worry about exact pixel/pt count and instead just resize/calculate by the size of your game resolution instead.

Comment: It's an entirely fair assumption that the issue may lie in your conversion of pt->px or in your ui setup, as if you are getting the exact notch size from the iphone, the issue must be how you're applying it in unity.

Comment: I've done exactly the way Unity official doc says I should but maybe the doc is wrong or I've misunderstood the doc. Do you know how to convert pt to px in Unity? More precisely, pt used in Xcode to px in Unity.